# Q learning for blackjack, reward function?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am currently learning reinforcement learning and am have built a blackjack game.

There is an obvious reward at the end of the game (payout), however some actions do not directly lead to rewards (hitting on a count of 5), which should be encouraged, even if the end result is negative (loosing the hand).

My question is what should the reward be for those actions ?

I could hard code a positive reward (fraction of the reward for winning the hand) for hits which do not lead to busting, but it feels like I am not approaching the problem correctly.

Also, when I assign a reward for a win (after the hand is over), I update the q-value corresponding to the last action/state pair, which seems suboptimal, as this action may not have directly lead to the win.

Another option I thought is to assign the same end reward to all of the action/state pairs in the sequence, however, some actions (like  hitting on count <10) should be encouraged even if it leads to a lost hand.

Note: My end goal is to use deep-RL with an LSTM, but I am starting with q-learning.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to start simple and use the rewards the game dictates. If you win, you'll receive a reward +1, if you lose -1.

It seems you'd like to reward some actions based on human knowledge. Maybe start with using epsilon greedy and let the agent discover all actions. Play along with the discount hyperparameter which determines the importance of future rewards,  and look if it comes with some interesting strategies.

This blog is about RL and Blackjack. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/playing-blackjack-using-model-free-reinforcement-learning-in-google-colab-aa2041a2c13d